# Redirection to mobile does not worl properly

Tags: redirect, mobile, asp-classic

I opened to my site a mobile site using the redirection:

but there is a problem, when a surfer find my page on google such as: http://tevalife.com/article.asp?id=3620 - he redircted to the mobile site homepage instead of to  the same page at the mobile site.
 please advise, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your detection script I can not offer a complete solution however adapting your redirect script to do something like this should work;

```
response.redirect("mobilesite.com/" & Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?" & Request.Querystring )
```

Where mobilesite.com is the mobile version of your site.